# How do you initialize struct size/length

Tags: c++

I Have to create a struct and run it in a loop which is not a problem but it has to run a specific number of times as the user chooses how do I do that ?

Ex:

```
struct employee
{
 Name
 Department
 Salary
};
```

If I want to run it ten times i can just use

```
for (int x=0, x<10, x++)
....
```

But what if I have to ask the user for the number and not keep it at 10 ?

---

Also any idea on how to error check the name using getline for wrong input (numbers).

Thanks a ton guys. I am new to c++ and trying to learn it so if you can give me examples with explanations it would be really appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Thanks for the input. I see how the name checking can be done now but I apologize for my unclear question.

when I declare the struct in main it asks me how many info I intend to put in my struct.
ex: employee e[10];

I dont know how to ask the user before this and make his/her response as a const int . (10 in this case is a const int).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that variable n will keep the entered value of the user.

```
int n;
```

Then the loop will look like

```
for ( int x = 0; x < n; x++ )
{
    // some code
}
```

The value in n can be entered by means of operator >>.

```
std::cin >> n;
```

To check that a name contains only letters you can apply algorithm `std::all_of` and standard C function `isalpha`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

//...

std::string name;

std::getline( std::cin, name );

if ( !name.empty() && std::all_of( name.begin(), name.end(), 
                                   []( char c ) { return std::isalpha( c ); } ) )
{
    std::cout << name << " is valid name" << std::endl;
}!
```